# Primeng UI for date time input not working in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeEUm.png

```
// Date Picker
<p-calendar  id="date1" [showIcon]="true" [readonlyInput]="true" [required]="true" ></p-calendar>
// Time Picker
<p-calendar [timeOnly]="true" inputId="timeonly"></p-calendar>
```

Comment: What version are you using? I have tried the code and worked fine for me (my version is 11). Other question, have you imported the modules in app.modules?

Comment: Hi, I have imported the Calendar module as mentioned on the official site and i am using Angular : 11.0.6 , CLI  : 11.0.7.
Primeng : 11.2.0
Icons : 4.1.0

Imports : {
            "src/styles.css",
             "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
             "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css"
}

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
a.ui-state-active {
background-color: red !important;
}
```

and this

```
.ui-button {
 background-color: red !important;
}
```

and if you try to use angular material datepicker easier than that use this

```
 <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle [for]="picker" matSuffix></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>

::ng-deep datepicker-value-example .mat-form-field-label{
   color:red;
}

::ng-deep .mat-datepicker-toggle{
   color:red;
}
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-underline{
background: red;
}
```

and the best way

for example
[enter link description here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-datepicker-qj73og)

```
::ng-deep .mat-focused .mat-form-field-label {
 /*change color of label*/
 color: white !important;
}

::ng-deep.mat-form-field-underline {
 /*change color of underline*/
 background-color: white !important;
} 

::ng-deep.mat-form-field-ripple {
 /*change color of underline when focused*/
 background-color: white !important;;
}

::ng-deep .mat-form-field-label {
 /*change color of label*/
 color: white !important;
}


mat-datepicker-toggle {
 color: white !important;
}
```

hope that to help you

Comment: Hi,How to do the same for time ? There is nothing mentioned on the official page for time input.